# Python MySQL query execution times differences between python environments

Tags: python, mysql, performance, miniconda

I have the following python code snippet, that performs very differently (execution time) between two miniconda environments, and I’m struggling to understand the root cause:

```
import mysql.connector as mdb

db = mdb.connect(   
    host = '<host>',
    user = '<user>',
    passwd = '<password>',
    db = '<schema>')

crsr = db.cursor()

sql = "select * from table_name;”
crsr.execute(sql)

while True:
    row = crsr.fetchone()
    # do something… - has been commented out to minimise testing “noise”
    if row == None:
    break

db.close()
```

I’m running the above script against the same MySQL database (8.0.16) and the same table with ~370K rows, yet it takes 3 seconds in an old python environment (3.6.8), while it takes 31 seconds in a newer one (3.9.16). These test results are constant and repeatable.

First miniconda environment (execution time: 3 seconds):

```
python=3.6.8
mysql-connector-python=8.0.16
```

Second miniconda environment (execution time: 31 seconds - x10 times longer):

```
python=3.9.16
mysql-connector-python=8.0.33
```

Can anyone suggest a reason for the poor performance with the later software version? And a way to address it?

Thanks

### ** Update **

This seems to be related to the python version. I tried the following third miniconda environment and still faced the longer execution time:

```
python=3.9.16
mysql-connector-python=8.0.16
```

The issue still appears with `python 3.8`, but not with `python 3.7` or below.

Question remains - what causes theh significant longer execution times for fetchone() in later python versions?

Comment: assuming all other equal, i would ask this question directly to the maintainers of the mysql-connector-python package. There migh tbe a bug.

Comment: Have you tested if the different python version or the different `mysql-connector-python` version is causing this issue?

Comment: Fair point @FlyingTeller - I've added an update, as it seems to be related to the python version rather than to the mysql-connector-python version

Comment: Run each timing test twice -- It may be a caching issue.